How much energy does active transport require in phosphorylation?
I know that active transport requires ATP in order to go against the concentration gradient.
But I somehow can't seem to find information on how much energy it needs.
So, my questions are:

What quantities does the energy required for active transport depend on? (If so, is there a formula for evaluating them?)

How much energy is needed for active transport in Oxidative phosphorylation and Photophosphorylation?


Thank you in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to SE BIology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to find out how the site operates. We'll know when you have done that by the badge that appears against your name. Your question is not totally clear because it does not indicate what is being transported. Do you mean the transport of protons at three stages of the electron transport chain? If you do, please edit your question to indicate this. Then reflect on the fact that this process is used to set up an electro-chemical gradient to generate ATP, and revise the question to eliminate what you thought you knew.
